# Axis2 v. 1,6,2 Eclipse plugin works fine on Kepler but not Luna

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis

I have copied these jars

org.apache.axis2.eclipse.service.plugin_1.6.2

org.apache.axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin_1.6.2

to plugins directory. Works with Kepler but not Luna. Initially tried extracting the jars to the dropins directory that never worked.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Try starting Eclipse with the -clean option.

Comment: Tried -clean option. Didn't work